# How do I Install firefox on Ubuntu Server 22.04 (Jammy) offline

Tags: firefox

So I downloaded the .tar file for firefox, tried to untar it and run the file. The browser then popped up and said it needs snap support to install. I am looking for an airgap install of Firefox on Ubuntu, without install snap. If I absolutely have to install snap I will, but I am air-gapped which means another sideload. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: See the Mozilla help page for this topic: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/install-firefox-linux#w_install-firefox-from-mozilla-builds

Comment: That is where I started before coming here. When I untar that file, it then asks for snap. Does anyone know a way around that?

Comment: If I am stuck installing snap to get firefox, does anyone know if I have to have a persistent internet connection to have snap install a "side loaded" package?

Comment: The limited description so far suggests that perhaps you didn't follow the "Install Firefox from Mozilla builds" instructions completely, since that method does not require snapd. [Edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1491840/edit) to show us the complete terminal session of the process you followed so we can see your exact inputs and the complete outputs.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, download Firefox from the official website:

Open a terminal

Run on it

```
cd ~/Downloads

wget https://archive.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/119.0.1/linux-x86_64/en-US/firefox-119.0.1.tar.bz2
```

Once the file has been downloaded, it can be located in the 'Downloads' folder.

Extract the file using the following command in that terminal:

```
 tar -xjf firefox-119.0.1.tar.bz2
```

We should now have an extracted folder called 'firefox'.

We need to move the folder to '/opt' with the following command:

```
 sudo mv firefox /opt
```

Now, we will create a link to launch the web browser from the terminal.

Run the following command to create the link to Firefox

```
sudo ln -s /opt/firefox/firefox /usr/bin/firefox
```